# Game characters not taking damage correctly - python 3.6

Tags: python

Note: This is a basic combat game, and I can't seem to get the human to take damage - yet the zombie takes damage fine. I can't figure out what is causing the issue - wether its data types or something else entirely. I've tried retyping the variables. The issue came about when I tried to add logic for combat between more than one zombie and human, I think there may be a conflict between this logic and the combat logic.

```
# Variable - UnitStats
HumanHealth = 85
HumanArmour = 0
HumanDamage = 15
HumanPeircing = 0

ZombieHealth = 60
ZombieArmour = 0
ZombieDamage = 40
ZombiePeircing = 0
                     
AttackPhase = ""

HumanNums = 0
HumanNums = int(HumanNums)
ZombieNums = 0
ZombieNums = int(ZombieNums)

print("Pick the number of zombies (1 or 2)")
ZombieNums = input()
ZombieNums = int(ZombieNums)
ZombieHealth = ZombieHealth * ZombieNums
ZombieArmour = ZombieArmour * ZombieNums
ZombieDamage = ZombieArmour * ZombieNums
ZombiePeircing = ZombiePeircing * ZombieNums

print("Pick the number of humans(1 or 2)")
HumanNums = input()
HumanNums = int(HumanNums)

HumanHealth = HumanHealth * HumanNums
HumanArmour = HumanArmour * HumanNums
HumanDamage = HumanDamage * HumanNums
HumanPeircing = HumanPeircing * HumanNums


print("Please type 'yes' to begin the attack phase")
AttackPhase = input().lower()

while AttackPhase == "yes":


    if ZombiePeircing > HumanArmour:
        HumanDamage = HumanDamage / 2

    if ZombiePeircing < HumanArmour:
        ZombieDamage = ZombieDamage / 2

    while True:

        ZombieHealth = ZombieHealth - HumanDamage
        HumanHealth = HumanHealth - ZombieDamage
        print("The zombie took damage, and is now on",ZombieHealth,"health")
        print("The human took damage, and is now on", HumanHealth,"health")
        print("Turn over.")
        time.sleep(2)

        if HumanHealth <= 0 and ZombieHealth > 0:
            print("The human has died, the zombie, which had",ZombieHealth," health won.")
            break

        if ZombieHealth <= 0 and HumanHealth > 0:
            print("The Zombie has died, the human, which had",HumanHealth," health won.")
```

Comment: when writing the title of a question, write about the programming concepts and not the specific use case- this will make your question more useful for others

Comment: @MadMeadyRevenge You've got a copy-paste error : `ZombieDamage = ZombieArmour * ZombieNums` should be `ZombieDamage = ZombieDamage * ZombieNums`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, its fixed now, units taking damage as normal